# Elasticsearch dead but pid file exists

Tags: elasticsearch

While trying to run the elasticsearch, I am getting the below message:

```
elasticsearch dead but pid file exists.
```

What could be the possible reason?

Appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Chandan

Answer (score -1):

I found that, the /var directory was full elasticsearch logs (**/var/log/elasticsearch**).

Deleted old logs and did a service elasticsearch start.

Working fine.

Thanks,

Chandan